# Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home4/msaraiva/public_html/test.php on line 8

Tags: php, parsing, find

I have this simple parser that i'm trying to make it work. But i get Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home4/msaraiva/public_html/test.php on line 8 error , that's on the 1st for each. But: on this url http://jantes.rupteur.com/jantes-alu/Alfa-Romeo-145 ( only 78 records) it works nice, but when i go to http://jantes.rupteur.com/jantes-alu/Alfa-Romeo-159 that has 399 records, the parser takes me to a fatal error, i tried everything and it's not working. PS: All Pages have the same html structure

Thanks you all

```
<?php
 include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html=file_get_html("http://jantes.rupteur.com/jantes-alu/Alfa-Romeo-145");

 foreach ($html ->find('td[valign=top]') as $t){
       foreach ($t ->find('h1') as $k)
          foreach ($t ->find('strong') as $g)
            echo $k;
            echo $g .'<br>';
       foreach ($html ->find('td[valign=top]') as $f)
           $num = explode('/>',$f);
           echo strip_tags($num[1]);           
 }
 echo '<br>';
 ?>
```

Comment: I believe you forgot some braces...

Comment: no, i guess not, because on the Alfa-Romeo-145 it works 100% correct
but on Alfa-Romeo-159 (that has a lot more records) it gives me the error, and i checked all the html and it's all the same

Comment: Also you variable naming sucks...

Comment: Also you indentation is... weird

Comment: Use braces and variable names that mean something so your code is readible. Then, use `is_object` to make sure that, before you call the `find` method of an object, that you actually have an object. The error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: forget all the "weird and naming of variables" , but th code is working to some urls, but not to the ones that has more records

Comment: It isn't something to "forget". You're having problems debugging your poorly conceived code -- that's why you should use better variable names, standard indentation, and braces. It makes your code readable and debugable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it happens because by default `file_get_html` function returns `false` if the html code lenght that you are parsing is bigger than 600000. Your second page is very large, so increase the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` constant in the simple_html_dom.php file.

```
define('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 9999999);
```

And listen to @PeeHaa and @Chris comments: there is nothing that can be just "forgotten"

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes across this

```
function get_data($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5;
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}

$url = "your url";

$htmlraw = "";
// this is the important bit (curl function is irrelevant)
$htmlraw = get_data($url); 
// use the str_get_html function instead.
$html = str_get_html($htmlraw);
```

hope that helps someone!